# GTK entry typing signal

Tags: c, gtk

What is the name of the signal that gets emitted when a user types some text at a gtk+ entry?

I am using GTK+ 2.24 in c.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `GtkEntry` is an instance of a `GtkEditable` which has three signals:

1. The `changed` signal is emitted at the end of a single user-visible operation
2. The `delete-text` signal is emitted when text is deleted from the widget by the user
3. The `insert-text` signal is emitted when text is inserted into the widget by the user

I assume you want the `insert-text` signal in your case.

Comment: Updated `GtkText` to `GtkEntry` as OP seems to be asking about `GtkEntry`, `GtkText` is deprecated & is an instance of `GtkOldEditable`

Comment: @another.anon.coward Sorry about that, I copied from incorrect documentation which said that GtkText was an instance of GtkEditable.